# Getting an old TYPO3 page to run locally

Tags: php, macos, typo3, local, mamp

I am, unfortunately, an absolute beginner when it comes to TYPO3.
I am a web designer and have received a call for help from a customer. A website is offline, because "the server was switched off".
When I looked at the backup he sent me, I realized that it is TYPO3 version 4.4.9 and runs with PHP 5. I strongly assume that the server will not (or will not want to) support the PHP version and therefore it will not run anymore.

Now I would get it running at least locally. But that is not possible.
I installed MAMP, could do a new and an old TYPO3 installation and also adapted the PHP version of MAMP so that I can use PHP5.

I have adapted the localconf.php so far that I have changed the DB information.
I also changed the domain path in the database, but I think this is the mistake, because I found little information about it.

When I open the SQL file in Visual Code, I find the following path under "LOCK TABLES 'cache_hash' WRITE":
/var/www/domain-name.com/web/typo3/*

Is this the path that needs to be adjusted?
If so, what is it?
Unfortunately I am not familiar with local installations.

I can do the installation/setup on a PC if it is easier.

Many, many thanks in advance for your help!
If any information is missing, please let me know.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with TYPO3, but to answer this bit at least: _Is this the path that needs to be adjusted? If so, what is it?_ Your MAMP installation will have a root folder for the site, likely something like [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`](/Applications/MAMP/htdocs) - the path will be relative to this.

Comment: Is there any error message when you call your local installation?

Answer (score 0):

if you transfer an installation you always should delete any caches. otherwise you will have local paths or domains which do not match any more.

as your installation is very, very old the structure differs widely from the structure of current TYPO3 versions.

1. you will find some `*cache*` files in the folder `/typo3conf/`. remove them
2. in the database you have some `*cache*` or `*_cf_*` tables. truncate them

you always should visit the install-tool (`my.domain.tld/typo3/install`) to check requirements. there also is a button to clear cache, which might replace step 2

after that you should be able to login to the backend.
there you might need to change a domain-record before the frontend has a chance to appear.

Further configuration could be needed, depending on state of securing the installation  (e.g. IP-mask settings) or installed extensions.

You also might night imagemagik or graphicsmagik for image processing. and make sure your PHP version is right. the latest PHP 5 probably does not match the requirement of this old TYPO3.